# getElementById in SVG document

Tags: javascript, svg, getelementbyid

I wrote a svg file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">

<svg width="1280pt" height="650pt" viewBox="0 0 1280 650" id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1"><script xlink:href="pathToPolyline.js"/><script><![CDATA[

alert(document);//returns [object SVG document]

//and tried

var path=document.getElementById('path1');//the problem line

alert(path);

]]></script>
<path id="path1" fill="#000000" d=" M 0.00 0.00 L 1280.00 0.00 L 1280.00 449.99 C 1276.46 444.19 1270.19 441.08 1265.59 436.31 C 1264.17 429.73 1265.36 422.91 1266.42 416.36 C 1267.19 413.43 1264.94 410.65 1262.45 409.42 C 1255.44 405.63 1247.99 402.68 12 .....
```

As in the comment line `alert(document);` alerts `[object SVG document]`.

But:

```
var path=document.getElementById('path1');
alert(path);
```

alerts `null`.

I also tried to put svg in an html page, also in an xhtml page, tried more thing but no result for now.

Any idea?

Comment: the svg represents expected view, i did not paste all the file here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the time you call `var path=document.getElementById('path1');`, the `path1` is not defined yet (it comes later on).

You ought to put the code after the path definition.

<s>However I'm not sure if you can put `<script>` tags inside a `<svg>`.</s>

Comment: @tuxia: I'm not wanting to push you into doing anything, but on Stack Overflow the way of saying thanks is accepting this answer :) Thank you.

Comment: @pimvdb: `<script>` is allowed anywhere inside the `<svg>`.

Answer (score 5):

Just to supplement pimvdb's answer:

You can use script tags in SVG: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/script.html

Furthermore, you can use [jQuery 1.2.6 with pure SVG documents](http://keith-wood.name/svg.html#tips), or any version of jQuery if you're using an HTML document with embedded SVG. In this case, you would be able to put your script tag wherever you like, and then use jquery's [$(document).ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) method to run the scripts after the document has been loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there you can create your own getElementById function and pass the svg as parameter,

```
function getElementById(root: any, id: string): any {
    var node = root;

    start: while (node) {
        if (node.id == id) {
            return node
        }

        if (node.firstChild) {
            node = node.firstChild;
            continue start;
        }

        while (node) {
            if (node === root) {
                break start;
            }

            if (node.nextSibling) {
                node = node.nextSibling;
                continue start;
            }

            node = node.parentNode;
        }
    }
    return null
}
```

So to find element in the svg...

```
var elem = getElementById(svg, circleElemId)
```